# Row bind multiple dataframes contained in a list of lists

Tags: r

Is there a way to row bind multiple data frames contained in a list of lists with few lines of code and minimising memory use?

`super_list` contains 20 sub lists, and each of those lists contains 100 data frames.

`super_list[[a]][[i]]` can be concatenated with `super_list[[b]][[j]]` only if `j == m`.

I want to create 100 data frames, each one is made from row binding 20 data frames, one from each sub list of `super_list`.

I'd like to avoid using a for loop to create 100 row binded dataframes, as this seems to require double the memory and seems inelegant.  Is there a better way?

To clarify further, the first data frame would be

```
df[[1]] <- bind_rows(super_list[[1]][[1]], super_list[[2]][[1]], ..., super_list[[20]][[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found purrr does transpose, this is working for me

```
library(purrr)
super_list <- super_list %>% purrr::transpose()
super_list <- lapply(super_list, bind_rows)
```

Comment: Also `super_list %>% purrr::transpose() %>% map(bind_rows)` should work?